# Dynamically set price using Typeform React embed

Tags: reactjs, typeform

Sense the price variable is already created by typeform, is there any way to send a number to that variable via an option similar to how you can set hidden values?

I have tried:

```js
<PopupButton
    id="12335"
    className={styles.card}
    hidden={{
        price: myPrice
    }}
>
```

and:

```js
<PopupButton
    id="12335"
    className={styles.card}
    variables={{
        price: myPrice
    }}
>
```

but neither set the price variable in typeform. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it is **not possible** to specify price for typeform payment via hidden field. Since hidden fields are passed via URL **anyone would be able to modify your price and pay any amount they choose**.

Variables and hidden fields are 2 different features. (Also, in your second code example you are using invalid `variables` prop. This prop is not supported by our lib.)

If you want to want to collect payments for multiple products using single typeform, you would need to calculate the price using [Typeform Logic](https://www.typeform.com/help/a/what-is-logic-360029116392/) right in your typeform. [This article about order and payment form](https://www.typeform.com/help/a/make-an-order-and-payment-form-360029614351/) might help you.